# Palindromic divisibility and primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, palindrome

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194956/618171) question:

Define odd-palindroming $X$ in base $b$, or $OP(X,b)$: Take an integer $X$ and write it in base $b$.  Then, reverse its digits and concatenate the reversed digits to the end of the number, without repeating the last digit. For example, $OP(11,7)$: $11=14_7$, $OP(11,7)=141_7=78$.  If the last few digits of $X_b$ are the same, odd-palindroming does not truncate them.  For example, $OP(122_b,b)=12221_b$ not $121_b$.

I started looking at under what conditions $OP(X,b)$ prime.

The rules vary depending on the relative values of $X$ and $b$.

Trivially, because $\forall b>X$, $OP(X,b)=X$, we get that $OP(X,b)$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $X$ is prime.  Equally trivially, when $b=X$, we get a prime if and only if $b^2+1$ is prime.  The numbers that would generate this result in the primes of [A002496](https://oeis.org/A002496).

We therefore are left with only $b\in\{2,3,4,...,X-1\}$.  We can start by applying some basic divisibility rules.

If $d$ is a prime factor of $b$, then $Y\equiv (Y\mod b) \mod d$.  Applying this, we get that $OP(X,b)$ is divisible by $d$ iff the leading digit of $X_b$ is divisible by $d$.  Trivially, this gives us that there is no $X$ such that $OP(X,p)$ is divisible by $p$ for any prime $p$.

If $b\equiv1\mod d$, then the sum of the digits of $Y_b$, denoted $S_b(Y)$, is equivalent to $Y\mod d$.  Applying this, we get that $OP(X,b)$ is divisible by $d$ iff $S_b(X)\equiv-(X \mod b)\mod d$.

If we denote $S_b'(Y)$ as the alternating sum of the digits of $Y_b$, then $Y$ is divisible by $b+1$ iff $S_b'(Y)\equiv0\mod (b+1)$.  Applying this, we get that $OP(X,b)$ is divisible by $b+1$ iff $(2S_b'(X)\mod(b+1))\equiv X\mod b$.

If every digit of $X_b$ is divisible by a prime $d$, then trivially $OP(X,b)$ is also divisible by $d$.

Some experimenting showed that for most numbers $X$, for some $b\in\{2,3,...,X-1\}$ you get $OP(X,b)$ is prime and for some $OP(X,b)$ is composite.  However, for $X=4$ you always get a prime and for $X=5$ you always get a composite.

Looking at the parity of $OP(X,b)$ gives us that for an odd $b$, there are never consecutive values of $X$ such that $OP(X,b)$ is odd, nor are there ever more than two consecutive values of $X$ such that $OP(X,b)$ is even.  In fact, for $b=2k+1$, we get the sequence for the parity of $OP(X,b)$, beginning with $X=b+1$ of: (1 odd followed by 1 even) k times, 1 odd, 2 evens, (1 odd followed by 1 even) k times, 1 odd, 2 evens, etc.  As a result, for $X>5$, there all always some odd values of $b$ that return an even number, which means that there always will be at least one value of $b$ such that $OP(X,b)$ is composite, meaning that $X=4$ is the last value of $X$ for which $OP(X,b)$ is always prime for $b\in\{2,3,...,X-1\}$.

While I didn't find any values of $X>5$ for which $\forall b\in\{2,3,...,X-1\}, OP(X,b)$ is composite, I can't prove whether or not they exist.  Can anyone provide a proof that they do/don't exist?

Comment: I would guess that the answer to your question is negative. You have roughly $OP(x,b)\in (x\sqrt{x},x^2)$, for $b\in\{2,\dots,x-1\}$. That is, you are roughly picking $x$ random numbers from the interval $(x\sqrt{x},x^2)$, where I would guess that the odds of never picking a prime in those trials tend to $0$ for large $x$. (i.e. the number of primes you will find grows - [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wEuQ.jpg) for $x\le 10^4$.)